# How to create a combination generator where order does not matter but being limited from a specific range of Sum? Using Excel VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

How to create a combination generator where order does not matter but being limited from a specific range of Sum? Using Excel VBA macro. Pls help ive been trying to solve this for years not really good at excel vba.. need actual precise codes..

Comment: Post a **small** sample of your input and desired output.

Comment: This might be an interesting question. [If only](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple example that uses an incrementing binary pattern to generate combinations of a set of items.

The items can be either numbers or text values.  I am using column **B** as a *"helper column"* to hold the binary pattern, but an array could be substituted.
Place your items in column **A** and run this short macro:

```
Sub Generate()
    Dim i As Long, s As String
    Dim j As Long, K As Long, N As Long
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim answer As String
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    K = 1
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To (2 ^ N) - 1
        s = wf.Dec2Bin(i, N)
        For j = 1 To N
            Cells(j, 2).Value = Val(Mid(s, j, 1))
        Next j
        answer = ""
        For j = 1 To N
            If Cells(j, 2) = 1 Then answer = answer & "," & Cells(j, 1)
        Next j
        Cells(K, 3) = Mid(answer, 2)
        K = K + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

For example:

[image]

Because there are `(2^N)-1` combinations for `N` items, there is a practical limit to the number of items that can be placed in column **A**.